# Javascript to Microsoft SQL Server (AJAX request)

Tags: javascript, php, asp.net, sql-server, ajax

I have a problem, how can i select data from my database (Microsoft SQL Server) from my javascript by an AJAX request.
I know I need a "server language", but it seems that PHP cannot do this !

How can I do ?

Thank you !

Comment: Is this a PHP based question or asp.net? because you have given tags of both php and asp.net

Comment: Sure you can do this in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php

Comment: Thanks your for answer, this is both ! In fact, I don't know if it can be done in php or in asp.net(extreme beginner in asp.net, I've never touched this !)

Comment: You simply need to call an AJAX function and then return data from server side back to client side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP is a server side language. Drivers are created for thee PHP package that allow them to interface with several different types of database architecture systems. In this case, the `SQL Server` would be connected to through the `sqlsrv` drivers for PHP.

A simple query to the database looks like the following:

```
-- query.php --

$serverName = "serverName\sqlexpress";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbName", "UID"=>"username", "PWD"=>"password" );
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Person";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
if( $stmt === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

if( sqlsrv_fetch( $stmt ) === false) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$name = sqlsrv_get_field( $stmt, 0);
echo $name; //maybe the name is "George"
```

This establishes the connection, and then attempts to query the database. As we're just retrieving one row, we use `sqlsrv_fetch()` to attempt to populate the `$stmt` variable. If it works, then we'll get `$name` as a return from the row at column with index `0`. This will return the value of `$name` to the `success function` of our `ajax call` (as illustrated below)

The `$.ajax()` is simple. Figure out what element is going to fire the ajax call, then just do it..

```
$('element').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'query.php',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data); //will show George in the console
            //otherwise it will show sql_srv errors.
        }
    });
});
```

**Resources**

1. [sqlsrv_connect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php)
2. [sqlsrv_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php)
3. [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

For connecting to SQL Server... You can use this code...

```
public function connect() {
    $dsn = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=xxxxx;Port=1433;Database=yyyy";
    $data_source='zzzz';
    $user='dbadmin';
    $password='password';
    // Connect to the data source and get a handle for that connection.
    $conn=odbc_connect($dsn,$user,$password);
    if (!$conn) {
        if (phpversion() < '4.0')
        {
                exit("Connection Failed: . $php_errormsg" );
            }
        else
        {
                exit("Connection Failed:" . odbc_errormsg() );
        }
    }
    return $conn;
}
```

Please note, here I have created a data source. This code is using ODBC as you can see. ;)
And this connection is using Sql Authentication.
Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

**Asp.net**

Client Side Code

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "ViewData.aspx/GetTransitNameById",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: '{"Transitid":"' + id + '"}',
            success: function (result) {
             // You got the required data in result.d
            var finalresult = result.d;
            }
        });
```

Server Side Code

```
   [WebMethod]
     public static string GetTransitNameById(int Transitid)
    {
        string name = "";
        try
        {
            oohMonitoringManager om = new oohMonitoringManager();
            name = om.GetTransitNameByTransitId(Transitid);
            // here you got what you needed. 
            // name contains the data that you have to return back to the javascript ajax function

        }
        catch (Exception a1)
        { }

        return name;
    }
```